# using jquery to sum the text box value in the child repeater control and show the total in the label in footer

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying this code for in jquery to sum the text box value in the child repeater control and show the total in the label in footer. I get `null is null or not an object` error.

```
function display(objSecName) {
    var objsec = objSecName;
    // var lablTotAmount = document.getElementById(objSecName);
    alert(objsec);
    $('.totamt input[type=text]').each(function () {
        $(this).change(function () {
            alert(calsum());
        });
    });

    function calsum() {
        var Total = 0;
        var limtamt = 120000;

        $('.totamt input[type=text]').each(function () {
            if (!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length != 0) {
                Total += parseFloat($(this).val());
                document.getElementById(lblTotalAmountId80C).value = Total;
            }
        });
        return Total;
    };
}
```

Comment: Code dumps are NOT useful. Try to debug your code first and then reduce it to the actual problem to only the necessary and more ppl will help.

Comment: You could also make a jsfiddle to give an example of the problem you are encountering

Answer (score 0):

Hmm, you should try to limit your code a bit when posting here. 
I cleared it up a bit for you.
Most likely the isNaN is a bit annoying in this case, I replaced that with the jquery-variant isNumeric.

```
function display(objSecName) {
  $('.totamt input[type=text]').change(function () {
     alert(calsum());
  });

  function calsum() {
    var total = 0;
    $('.totamt input[type=text]').each(function () {
      var value = parseFloat(this.value);
      if ($.isNumeric(value)) {
        total += value;
      }
    });
    document.getElementById(lblTotalAmountId80C).value = total;
    return total;
  };
}
```